# LoadContent does not work in my components

Tags: xna

For some reason the LoadContent method does not get called in my Components.
For example I have Game class in which I do:

```
//Game.cs
protected override void LoadContent() {
  editor = new Editor(...);
  Components.Add(editor);
}

//Editor.cs
public class Editor : DrawableGameComponent{
  Game game;
  public Editor(Game game, ...):base(game){
     this.game = game;
  }

  //THIS method never gets called!
  protected override void LoadContent() {
          background = game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("background");
          base.LoadContent();
  }
}
```

Any tips?

EDIT: When you keep in mind the order of Initialize and LoadContent everything works out fine!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suspect your trouble is due to the [Initialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.game.initialize.aspx) function.  `LoadContent` is called by `Initialize`.  There are two things you need to check for:

1. Verify that you are creating and adding your drawable game component in Game.cs before `base.Initialize()` is called.  In the code above, you are creating and adding the component in the `LoadContent` function of Game.cs, which occurs after `Initialize`.
2. Verify that the `Initialize` function in your `Editor` class is calling the base `Initialize` function:

   ```
   public override void Initialize()
   {
       base.Initialize();
   }
   ```

Check out this [blog post](http://nickgravelyn.com/2008/11/life-of-an-xna-game/) by Nick Gravelyn for more information.  Particularly relevant to your question, in his post, Nick writes that:

1. First you’ll get a call to Initialize. This is where you generally put non-graphical initialization code for your game*. You also need to make sure you call base.Initialize(). When you do, the game does a few things:

   1. Calls Initialize on each GameComponent in the Components collection.
   2. Creates the GraphicsDevice.
   3. Calls LoadContent on the game.
   4. Calls LoadContent for each DrawableGameComponent in the Components collection.

Comment: Thanks, you led me to discover my problem. I put the solution into my question!

Comment: New link to inactive blog at [Internet Archives](https://web.archive.org/web/20111107064918/http://blog.nickgravelyn.com/2008/11/life-of-an-xna-game/).

Answer (score 4):

LoadContent will not be called if a GraphicsDeviceManager has not been registered before base.Initialize is called. The following code correctly registers a GraphicsDeviceManager for the game.

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! Everyone's comments on this issue seem to consist of "Make sure you call base.Initialize()", but this is an absolutely critical point. I've been trying to track down this problem for quite a while, and you've finally helped me out.

Comment: Curiously, it seems you don't even need to assign the GraphicsDeviceManager to something. You can just magically call `new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);` and it works just fine. Obviously, as is, you have the benefit of having a reference to it, but it seems to just "click" and work regardless.